# how to call method multiple time on button click

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have the code below to allow me to add data from a excel sheet directly into a sing given database, now I would like to know how I would be able to call the method multiple times to add data from two different excel file at once, the is a button which calls this method once clicked, using multi-threading.

```
private void AddToDatabase()
{
    using (OleDbConnection connection =
                new OleDbConnection(excelConnectionString))
    {
         connection.Open();
         CheckNumeberOfSheets(connection);
    }
}
```

Button code;

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AddToDatabase();
}
```

Comment: I suppose the excelConnectionString would change for the second Excel file, right?

Comment: that would be the case as the name of the file would,

Comment: Just make the excelConnectionString a parameter?

Comment: no.. i want the data from both files to be added at the smae  time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you can pass a string to your method AddToDatabse like

```
   private void AddToDatabase(string fileName){
    if(fileName.Equals("yourfirstFile"))
     {
      using (OleDbConnection connection =
            new OleDbConnection(excelConnectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                CheckNumeberOfSheets(connection);

            }
      }
    else if(fileName.Equals("yoursecondfile"))
     {
      using (OleDbConnection connection =
            new OleDbConnection(excelConnectionString2))
            {
                connection.Open();
                CheckNumeberOfSheets(connection);

            }
      }
    }
```

and then call it like this

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         AddToDatabase("yourfirstFile");
         AddToDatabase("yoursecondFile");
    }
```

Comment: this will first do the first file and then the second but i would like to get them added in parele in one conection to the database

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1: create a class named "ClassFiles"**

```
public class ClassFiles
{

private String fileName;
private String excelConnectionString;


public String getFileName()
 return fileName;

public void setFileName(String fileName)
{
 this.fileName=fileName;
}

public String getExcelConnectionString()
 return excelConnectionString;

public void setExcelConnectionString(String excelConnectionString)
{
 this.excelConnectionString=excelConnectionString;
}
}
```

**Step 2: In your main class, add the fileName along with excelConnection String like:**

```
public class MainClass{


private void AddFilesToDB(List<ClassFiles>fileDetails){

  for(ClassFiles fileDeteil : fileDetails){

            using (OleDbConnection connection =
            new OleDbConnection(fileDeteil.getExcelConnectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                CheckNumeberOfSheets(connection);

            }

  // as well as u can get the file name..
           String fileName=fileDeteil.getFileName();
    }
}

public Static void main(string args[]){

    List<ClassFiles> addDetails =new ArrayList<ClassFiles>();
    //now add the no of files into the list
     ClassFiles objFile1=new ClassFiles();
     objFile1.setFileName("filename1");
     objFile1.setExcelConnectionString("excelConnectionString1");
     addDetails.add(objFile1);

     ClassFiles objFile2=new ClassFiles();
     objFile2.setFileName("filename2");
     objFile2.setExcelConnectionString("excelConnectionString2");
     addDetails.add(objFile2);

     and so on..
     then call the function for further process.,

    new MainClass().AddFilesToDB(addDetails);
  }
```

**`hope it ll help you..`**

Comment: this would do it in a queue like manner but i would like to add the data all data into the table in parrallel